# How can I run a business network as a second peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I followed [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org) tutorial to deploy my business network onto Hyperledger Fabric.

In the *connection.json* file, I added two peers and in the channel, too. Now, I see that the network is working fine with the first peer.

How can I check the application as the second peer? I mean, if I make a transaction as the first peer, how can I check as a second peer, that it's been updated in the copy of Ledger with the second peer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the logs of the docker container to see if there is activity on the 2nd peer.

You could also stop the first peer with a command like `docker stop peer0.org1.example.com` then try `composer network list -c <admin@my-network>` - this should failover to the remaining 2nd peer (called peer1 !)